# Pseudo-Boolean function vs Boolean function

Tags: functions, terminology

What is the **difference between a pseudo-Boolean function and a Boolean function**?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Boolean_function) states that a Boolean function is a special case of a pseudo-Boolean function, but I do not understand in what way. It seems like both are of the form
$$
f \colon \{0,1\}^n \to \mathbb{R}
$$
However, this does not really help me in distinguishing the two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Boolean function, the range is a subset of $\{0,1\}$.

For a pseudo-Boolean function, the range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but not necessarily a subset of $\{0,1\}$.

For example . . .

- The function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\mathbb{R}\;\,$given by
  $$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\max(x_1,...,x_n)$$
  is a Boolean function.$\\[10pt]$

  The function $g:\{0,1\}^n\to\mathbb{R}\;\,$given by
  $$g(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1 + \cdots + x_n$$
  is a pseudo-Boolean function, but not a Boolean function (unless $n=1$).